# Infection rate time-series analysis

Tags: time-series, prevalence

We have some surveillance data from a hospital that include infections with antibiotic-resistant bacteria and the number of admissions, patient-days so that I can calculate incidence and prevalence. These are monthly datapoints, for now they span 2020 and 2022, but will eventually include 2021 (and maybe 2019 as well).

We are interested in identifying periods of time in which the infections "change significantly", if this is a sensical question on its own.

First of all, can this type of question be answered based on the data we have?

And second, would something like a poisson regression be suitable for this?

Comment: You can indeed do something to analyse trends in these infections, but the date range is quite short (~36 observations?) and this could make it difficult to see significant change. A good first approach would be Poisson regression with exposure (offset) defined by the patient-hours and some covariates to model temporal trends. If you have access to dates of individual infections or even daily data, you could do more.

Comment: What types of covariates are you referring to? And how would I identify specific time-points (?) at which significant change is observed? I may have access to the specific dates, but I have to check that.

Comment: Temporal covariates could be cosine, sine, or polynomial terms to model the variation across time. A graph of your infection counts (you can omit the y-axis labels if you desire) would help to choose these terms. To identify times of changes you could either inspect a linear or polynomial trend term, or you could use changepoints (see e.g. the R `segmented` package).

Comment: I have a more basic question. One of the assumptions of the poisson distribution is that each event is independent. Can we say that this holds for our data? Since infections spread, the probability of infection changes depending on the spread of the disease at that point in time. Is there a limit where we can say that the assumption is approximately met? Also, because we are analysing a few different infections independently, some of the counts include a bunch of zeroes and some of them none at all. Is it suitable to use a zero inflated poisson model?